# [Browser][cordova.js][xhrStatusChangeHandler] Could not XHR config.xml: Not Found

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to develop an app using ionic 4, angular 6, Nodejs 10 and need to integrate google maps. When I run my app, I always see this error in the dev tools browser console - `[Browser][cordova.js][xhrStatusChangeHandler] Could not XHR config.xml: Not Found`. Copied the full console at the end.

Following is the code I have -

`app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { GoogleMaps } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    GoogleMaps,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Following is my `app.component.ts` file -

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform, Nav } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { HomePage } from './home/home.page';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any;

  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Home',
      url: '/home',
      icon: 'home'
    },
    {
      title: 'List',
      url: '/list',
      icon: 'list'
    }
  ];

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.rootPage = HomePage;
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

`home.page.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap } from '@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Environment } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor( private platform: Platform) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.platform.ready();
    await this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    Environment.setEnv({
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_RELEASE': 'Agktkllffff1xGYLjDF0v1i2RSDrqDLjEmDdLI',
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_DEBUG': ''
    });

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');
  }
}
```

`home.page.html`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h3>GoogleMaps</h3>
  <div id = "map_canvas">
    <button ion-button (click)="onButtonClick($event)">Demo</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

I checked my Google Map API key and it doesn't has problem and double checked that I am using the correct one. My account is also fine and shouldn't be a problem with that. I am wondering what is causing this issue. The command that I am using to run my application is -

```
ionic cordova run browser -l
```

The url that opens up is `http://172.29.54.8:8100/home`

`console.log` error details -

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
cordova.js:1066 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1059 Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
cordova.js:1059 Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
bootstrap.js:15 Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.js:15
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:485
timer @ zone.js:2054
setTimeout (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2075
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2090
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1394
checkReady @ bootstrap.js:13
./node_modules/@ionic-native/core/index.js @ index.js:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:83
./node_modules/@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx/index.js @ index.js:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:83
./src/app/app.module.ts @ app.component.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:83
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:83
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:83
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
cordova.js:1024 adding proxy for common
cordova.js:1024 adding proxy for PluginEnvironment
cordova.js:1024 adding proxy for CordovaGoogleMaps
cordova.js:1024 adding proxy for PluginLocationService
cordova.js:1024 adding proxy for PluginGeocoder
cordova.js:1024 adding proxy for StatusBar
cordova.js:1024 adding proxy for Device
cordova.js:1024 adding proxy for SplashScreen
StatusBarProxy.js:23 StatusBar is not supported
zone.js:2969 GET http://172.29.54.8:8100/config.xml 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2969
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:3001
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1394
readConfig @ cordova.js:891
initAndShow @ SplashScreenProxy.js:154
(anonymous) @ SplashScreenProxy.js:165
build @ cordova.js:51
require @ cordova.js:66
localRequire @ cordova.js:47
exports.mapModules @ cordova.js:1352
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1152
f @ cordova.js:645
Channel.fire @ cordova.js:798
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1144
onScriptLoadingComplete @ cordova.js:1574
scriptLoadedCallback @ cordova.js:1591
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1545
wrapFn @ zone.js:1188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
error (async)
customScheduleGlobal @ zone.js:1666
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleEventTask @ zone.js:258
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1831
desc.set @ zone.js:1244
requireEnsure @ bootstrap:145
webpackAsyncContext @ .*\.entry\.js$ include: \.entry\.js$ namespace object:780
o @ ionic.core.js:6
t.In @ ionic.core.js:9
$ @ ionic.core.js:6
(anonymous) @ ionic.core.js:6
r @ ionic.core.js:6
(anonymous) @ ionic.core.js:6
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:14060
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:872
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:14051
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
resolvePromise @ zone.js:808
(anonymous) @ zone.js:724
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:25
(anonymous) @ 12.js:1
cordova.js:866 [Browser][cordova.js][xhrStatusChangeHandler] Could not XHR config.xml: Not Found
fail @ cordova.js:866
xhrStatusChangeHandler @ cordova.js:880
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
load (async)
customScheduleGlobal @ zone.js:1666
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleEventTask @ zone.js:258
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1831
readConfig @ cordova.js:886
initAndShow @ SplashScreenProxy.js:154
(anonymous) @ SplashScreenProxy.js:165
build @ cordova.js:51
require @ cordova.js:66
localRequire @ cordova.js:47
exports.mapModules @ cordova.js:1352
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1152
f @ cordova.js:645
Channel.fire @ cordova.js:798
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1144
onScriptLoadingComplete @ cordova.js:1574
scriptLoadedCallback @ cordova.js:1591
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1545
wrapFn @ zone.js:1188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
error (async)
customScheduleGlobal @ zone.js:1666
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleEventTask @ zone.js:258
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1831
desc.set @ zone.js:1244
requireEnsure @ bootstrap:145
webpackAsyncContext @ .*\.entry\.js$ include: \.entry\.js$ namespace object:780
o @ ionic.core.js:6
t.In @ ionic.core.js:9
$ @ ionic.core.js:6
(anonymous) @ ionic.core.js:6
r @ ionic.core.js:6
(anonymous) @ ionic.core.js:6
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:14060
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:872
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:14051
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
resolvePromise @ zone.js:808
(anonymous) @ zone.js:724
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:25
(anonymous) @ 12.js:1
SplashScreenProxy.js:163 [Browser][cordova.js][xhrStatusChangeHandler] Could not XHR config.xml: Not Found
(anonymous) @ SplashScreenProxy.js:163
fail @ cordova.js:869
xhrStatusChangeHandler @ cordova.js:880
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
load (async)
customScheduleGlobal @ zone.js:1666
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleEventTask @ zone.js:258
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1831
readConfig @ cordova.js:886
initAndShow @ SplashScreenProxy.js:154
(anonymous) @ SplashScreenProxy.js:165
build @ cordova.js:51
require @ cordova.js:66
localRequire @ cordova.js:47
exports.mapModules @ cordova.js:1352
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1152
f @ cordova.js:645
Channel.fire @ cordova.js:798
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1144
onScriptLoadingComplete @ cordova.js:1574
scriptLoadedCallback @ cordova.js:1591
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1545
wrapFn @ zone.js:1188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
error (async)
customScheduleGlobal @ zone.js:1666
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleEventTask @ zone.js:258
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1831
desc.set @ zone.js:1244
requireEnsure @ bootstrap:145
webpackAsyncContext @ .*\.entry\.js$ include: \.entry\.js$ namespace object:780
o @ ionic.core.js:6
t.In @ ionic.core.js:9
$ @ ionic.core.js:6
(anonymous) @ ionic.core.js:6
r @ ionic.core.js:6
(anonymous) @ ionic.core.js:6
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:14060
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:872
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:14051
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
resolvePromise @ zone.js:808
(anonymous) @ zone.js:724
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:25
(anonymous) @ 12.js:1
bootstrap.js:10 Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 15597 ms
StatusBarProxy.js:23 StatusBar is not supported
cordova.js:1024 adding proxy for map_0_605401752643
util.js:225 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    xhr.open("get", "/config.xml", true);
    xhr.send();
} catch(e) {
    fail('[Browser][cordova.js][readConfig] Could not XHR config.xml: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

Try to find these lines in **cordova.js** file of the platform.
I guess your application is in a sub-folder. Hence the error. Change it to

```
try {
    xhr.open("get", "/<foldername>/config.xml", true);
    xhr.send();
} catch(e) {
    fail('[Browser][cordova.js][readConfig] Could not XHR config.xml: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the problem when I run command

```
ionic cordova build browser
```

and gulp wrong build content to the serve,

`www`unber `platforms/browser` is the correct one

the `www`under project folder is wrong one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am launching my app like the following
http://1.2.3.4/MyApp.BETA/

I think a better approach is to assume **current directory** instead of root. Therefor the fix should be:

```
xhr.open("get", "./config.xml", true);
```

Where is the source of this cordova.js?

Who should be notified to fix this? Cordova?

Thank you.